# why is this verbatim string not working as I expect for a unit test assert and showing a strange value in debugger?

Tags: c#, debugging, mstest, verbatim

[image]

QUESTION: Why does the debugger show "directagents\a\aanodide" instead of the value of the verbatim string @"directagents\aanodide".

***UPDATE***
This seems to be a ReSharper quirk.
To Reproduce:

1. Enter a literal string with a "\a" in it.
2. Apply the refactor "Change to Verbatim Sring"

   - "\a" becomes invisible in th verbatim string
   - "\a" is not really gone.

More evidence from immediate window showing Hand Typed VS. Copy/Paste.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

The debugger doesn't know that you use the compiler [verbatim](http://www.google.com/search?q=define%3averbatim) style to create the string. It just displays the string using the most common representation which isn't verbatim.

A verbatim string, besides accepting new line, also doesn't recognizes escape sequences so \a which is a bell character ends up as two characters in one case and as one character when not using the verbatim style.

You can lookup the reference for C# string literals [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: This is not my experience (visual studio 2010, .NET 4)

Comment: I think Matt is right - I retyped the line of code and it gave me a different result, which made me realize the bell character had gotten hidden in the string by the ReSharper refactor... I should also say "thanks" for making me think about the fact that the \a was a bell char :)